# How to check/see systemctl's running script logs?

Tags: services

Context, I have a python script added to services on systemctl to start on boot.

Thing is, I want to be able to check the actual script's logs, in case there are issues. I tried using the journalctl but all I got is the service logs themselves, not the actual python script logs.

The .service is as following:

```
[Unit]
Description=HA_Failsave
After=network-online.target
[Service]
ExecStart=sudo python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Home_Assistant_Keep_Alive/main.py
WorkingDirectory=/
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=pi
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution (https://fhackts.wordpress.com/2014/11/27/systemd-journal-not-showing-python-3-print/)

Just flush stdouts on the python script:

```
import sys
print('Hello')
sys.stdout.flush()
```